# Odoo 10 , how to inherit an qweb report on Odoo 10 Comunity version?

Tags: xml, odoo-10

i have tried to create an custom module, the module inherits account_invoice_report qweb, while i installed the module this error came out

```
Error context:
View `report_invoice_document_inherit_sale`
[view_id: 500, xml_id: sale.report_invoice_document_inherit_sale, model: n/a, parent_id: 436]
None" while parsing None:4, near
<data inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document" priority="15">
```

Could you guys please give me a hand to solve that error, Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of this methods define in this links:

https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/

or

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/qweb-html-report-template-inheritance-56716

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion